# OpenGL - Read only non-black pixels from screen

Tags: c, opengl, textures

I'm trying to implement the [IBFVS](http://www.win.tue.nl/~vanwijk/ibfvs.pdf) algorithm and am having trouble with one of the steps which is to store the a blended image that's in the frame buffer into a texture array.

My object on screen is a 3D bunny which has been texture mapped with a gray image and then blended with a noise image. I need to store only this blended texture into the original texture image so that I can use it in the next frame.

The problem is that if I use `glReadPixels()` or `glCopyTexImage2D()` to read in the pixels, I get the entire screen which includes the black background along with the bunny which is not useful since I'm only looking for the blended texture on the surface of the bunny.

Is there any way to selectively read pixels from the screen such that I only get the non-black values?

My code to generate the base texture:

```
glGenTextures(1, &FtTex);
for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 512; j++) {
        baseTex[i][j][0] =
            baseTex[i][j][1] =
            baseTex[i][j][2] = (GLubyte)128;
    }
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FtTex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, baseTex);
```

Generating noise:

```
glGenTextures(32, noiseTexImg);

int lut[256]; // lookup table to store dynamic profiles
int phase[NRES][NRES]; // stores the phase for each pixel in the noise pattern
int t;

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) lut[i] = i < 127 ? 0 : 255; // fill lookup table with block pulse

for (int i = 0; i < NRES; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < NRES; j++) phase[i][j] = rand() % 256;

for (int i = 0; i < NNoise; i++) {
    t = i * 256 / NNoise;
    for (int j = 0; j < NRES; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < NRES; k++) {
            noiseTex[j][k][0] =
                noiseTex[j][k][1] =
                noiseTex[j][k][2] = (GLubyte)lut[(t + phase[j][k]) % 255];
            noiseTex[j][k][3] = (GLubyte)(alpha * 255);
        }
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, noiseTexImg[i]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, NRES, NRES, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, noiseTex);
}
```

Drawing object with base texture:

```
glPushMatrix();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FtTex);
for (int i = 0; i < poly->ntris; i++) {
    Triangle* t = poly->tlist[i];
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        Vertex *v = t->verts[j];
        glColor3f(1., 1., 0.);
        glTexCoord2dv(v->tx); glVertex3f(v->x, v->y, v->z);
    }
    glEnd();
}
glPopMatrix();
```

Blending noise:

```
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(-1.5, -1.5, 0);
glScalef(3, 3, 3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, noiseTexImg[fctr % NNoise]);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER);
glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);       glVertex3f(0, 0, -40);
glTexCoord2f(0, tmax);    glVertex3f(0, 1, -40);
glTexCoord2f(tmax, 0);    glVertex3f(1, 0, -40);
glTexCoord2f(tmax, tmax); glVertex3f(1, 1, -40);
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
fctr++;
glPopMatrix();
```

Relevant portion of the display function:

```
drawObjectWithFt(); // draw with base image

/* blend noise */
blendNoise();

glReadPixels(0, 0, BRES, BRES, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, baseTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FtTex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, BRES, BRES, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, baseTex);
```

I'm on OpenGL 4.5 and most of the code is in C.

Any tips on how to do this much are much appreciated!

Comment: Render to a framebuffer object, to which a RGB**A** texture is attached. Clear to A=0. Using a framebuffer object you don't have to `glReadPixels` or `glCopyTexSubImage`, since you're rendering directly to the texture. And using the alpha channel allows you to blend it.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly then you're suggesting that I draw in the same manner to an FBO instead of the screen correct? In this case, the FBO will also have the black pixels after I've drawn my object and blended the noise image right? If my understanding is incorrect, can you please elaborate on what you're saying cause I don't fully get it. I'm quite new to OpenGL.

Comment: Are you currently using shaders?

Comment: @BinoyDalal: Consider this: A pixel is a tuple of several values in a certain range. Usually that range is normalized to [0…1] and other values are not allowed. So just by going with that your pixels **must** be either be black, or non black. But a pixel cannot *not* be. So you need an additional channel, like the alpha channel to mark it's weight or opacity. And that's what I suggest here: Use a render target that in addition to color also captures opacity, so that you can use it for *blending* in a later state.

Comment: @BinoyDalal: Maybe you should start with not implementing IBVFS but just getting regular alpha blending to work. You know, read images with an alpha channel into a texture and draw those with triangles. Write some shaders (or look into old-and busted texture environment mode) to get a feel for the different modes like *decal*, *modulate*, *blend*.

Comment: @AdaRaider no i'm not using shaders.

Comment: @datenwolf i have a working 2D version of it already. But I understand your idea of using the alpha channel now. I'm going to give it a shot and report back. Thanks!